# Find the value of $n$ in this binomial expression

Tags: combinatorics

> A student is allowed to select at most $n$ books from a collection of $2n+1$ books. If the total number of ways in which he can select at least one book is $63$, find the value of $n$.

My work:

I made the equation, $$\binom{2n+1}{1}+\binom{2n+1}{2}+\cdots+\binom{2n+1}{n}=63$$
But I can't form a closed form for the binomial expression. Any help is greatly appreciated.

I know $$\binom{n}{r}+\binom{n}{r+1}=\binom{n+1}{r+1}$$

Comment: Who says there's a convenient closed formula?  Maybe this is just a matter of numerical work.  $63$ is small so this should not be hard.

Comment: @lulu i tried ..the answer's given is $3$ but when we put $3$...it is equal to $58$

Comment: Check your arithmetic.  $3$ works.  $\binom 71 = 7$ , $\binom 72=21$, and $\binom 73=35$.

Comment: @lulu oh yeah...im dumb

Comment: should i delete this? @lulu

Comment: It got a good answer (from @Klaus) via symmetry, I'd leave it up.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By the binomial theorem,
$$2^{2n+1} = (1+1)^{2n+1} = \sum\limits_{k = 0}^{2n+1} {2n+1 \choose k}.$$
As ${2n+1 \choose k} = {2n+1 \choose 2n+1-k}$, we can remove half of the terms to get
$$2^{2n} = \sum\limits_{k = 0}^n {2n+1 \choose k} = 1 + \sum\limits_{k = 1}^n {2n+1 \choose k}.$$
This leads to the simple equation $2^{2n}-1 = 63$ in your case.